# Managing different client codes in branches

Tags: java, git, version-control, bitbucket

I'm fairly new to git and this might be a question with an obvious answer:

So I've got a project/framework I'm using to manage a bunch of automated test cases. So the folder code structure is below.

```
Java
|-Package1
    |-Common code
    |-tests
        |- Client1 tests
        |- Client2 tests
        |
        |
        |- ClientN tests
```

Is it recommended to maintain client specific code in different branches? Or is it better to make a copy of the project and maintain in different repos per client? Basically each client has different tests written on top of same core using Selenium/TestNG.

Comment: How is the question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Comment: Client per repo is technically possible.... but it is an overkill (plus a pain in the butt in order to share stuff between them). You should handle client per branch or use flags and keep a single code-base.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are possible but I think in here it is more a question of maintainability. I this case I would go for the separate repos approach but with an extra: [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

There are 2 reasons for choosing this approach:

- complexity of maintaining separate branches. Each client would have a development workflow. That means you will probably have to branch off when you want to add a new feature to one of your clients from the existing client branch and things get messy. At some point you may start to confuse branches;
- the second reason is keeping up with the common code; if you have the clients on separate branches how do you keep up with the common code updates? regular merges / rebases ... ? A lot more overhead on the long term than using separate git repos.

With the separate repos/submodule approach you would get something like this:

```html
Common Code Repo ( referred to as CCR )

Client 1 Repo has CCR as submodule
Client 2 Repo has CCR as submodule
...
Client N Repo has CCR as submodule
```

Like this everything is managed independently and every project can have its own flow without having dependencies and messy branching structure.